# Codificação da View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou com problemas para setar a codificação de uma página que fiz no *ASP.NET Core* (fica aparecendo **?** em letras com acentos).

Nos *MVC* antigos você fazia a configuração no *web.config* do projeto, mas agora esse arquivo não existe, e não tenho a menor ideia de como transformar a configuração dele para o *Startup.cs* (onde as configurações são feitas agora).

Comment: Também estou com o mesmo problema e procuro por uma solução. Procurando

Comment: A resposta abaixo é a solução, também vi a mesma resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45577036/7762411)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho a solução para o seu problema, siga os seguintes passos:
1. Abra o arquivo que contem as palavras com acentuação;
2. Vá ao **File->Save As**;
3. E lá carregue na setinha do botão *Save* e, *Save with Encoding*.
4. De seguida escolha a opção do UTF-8.
5. Não se preocupe se o VS pedir para substituir o ficheiro

Arranque o projecto e veja.